# sqrt in C on Ubuntu

Tags: c

I have to write a program that finds square root of an integer that is input by a user. But I met a problem - program does not calculate the sqrt. I searched for the problem on the Internet, read all solutions, but they did not help me. On this forum there are many questions on this topic, but solutions described there are not working for me.

Actually, `sqrt` function does not work when an integer is input by a user. When I set a value it works perfectly. In other words, it finds a sqrt of constant, but not of variable.

I compile it with this code(as everywhere is written) `gcc -o sqrt -lm sqrt.c`

I am working on Ubuntu.

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
int a;
double b=sqrt(a);
scanf("%i", &a);
printf("sqrt of integer is %lf", b);
getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: In your case, `-lm` is being linked by gcc by default. Otherwise, you should put `-lm` **after** the file that uses it. In general, when linking, if `A` needs `B`, then `B` should come after it.

Comment: You should certainly read some more C tutorials or read them more carefully if you make such a mistake

Comment: @H2CO3, I just started learning C(and I mentioned it my previous questions - this is my 4th question). Please do not write comments to my questions that does not contain any helpful information for me. I ask a question here only after doing research on the web.

Comment: @Emilaze I didn't mean to be rude, but in this particular case, in my opinion, it would have required some intuition/common sense only to see what was wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3, it's ok. I think we just misunderstood each other. And again - for me now it is too early to recognize my mistakes while typing. I'm learning step by step, so I so I don't know some functions rules of language yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> int a;
> double b=sqrt(a);
> scanf("%i", &a);
> ```

You're using the variable (`a`) before initializing it. The `scanf` should go before the `sqrt`.

Comment: @cnicutar, have you noticed how answers to insignificant questions  on SO get very high votes? Makes you wonder... Seems like most of the high rep guys are not actually extremely knowledged, but just fast in answering.

Comment: @Shahbaz http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem Also, I don't consider myself extremely knowledgeable ;) As the FAQ states, the reputation is a measure of how much the community trusts you, not a measure of knowledge or wisdom.

Answer (score 3):

To add something to the two good answers already written: you need to keep in mind that the primary sequence of instructions in C is linear - the instrction written first is executed first. If we were talking about math, it would be fine to say 'let b be the **function** sqrt(a), then find out what b(a) is'. You can actually do this in C by defining your own functions, but that's something else. NB: the computer doesn't do what you think you told it to do. It does what you told it to do.